# Evitar edição no campo

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte: o usuário digita o cep dele, e então é preenchido automaticamente, `estado`(select) `cidade`(select), `rua`(input) e `bairro`(input), quando o usuário digita seu cep e por exemplo é um cep completo (Cidade, Estado, Rua e Bairro) os campos eram desabilitados para edição utilizando `Disable`. Quando o cep é somente da Cidade (Cidade e estado) os campos Bairro e rua ficam habilitados para digitar. Para isto estava usando este script:

```
$("#ZipCode").change(function () {
    var zipCodeValue = $(ZipCode).val();
    var url = '@Url.Action("ReturnZipCode", "Ajax")';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: { zipCode: zipCodeValue },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("City").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("State").disabled = true;
            $('#State').val(data.StateID).change();
            setTimeout(setCity, 1000);
            function setCity() {//insere a cidade após 3 segundos
                $('#City').val(data.CityID).change();
                $('#CityID').val($('#City').val());
            }

            if (data.AddressName != "") {
                document.getElementById("Address").disabled = true;
                $('#Address').val(data.AddressName);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Address").disabled = false;
                $('#Address').val("");
            }

            if (data.Neighborhood != "") {
                document.getElementById("Neighborhood").disabled = true;
                $('#Neighborhood').val(data.Neighborhood);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Neighborhood").disabled = false;
                $('#Neighborhood').val("");
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Error' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

Com a ajuda de [Lucas Costa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/32827/lucas-costa) e [Gabriel Falieri](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/62143/gabriel-falieri) alterei de Desable para readOnly, e parcialmente foi resolvido, como pode ver no código:

```
$("#ZipCode").change(function () {
    var zipCodeValue = $(ZipCode).val();
    var url = '@Url.Action("ReturnZipCode", "Ajax")';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: { zipCode: zipCodeValue },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("City").readOnly = true;
            document.getElementById("State").readOnly = true;
            $('#State').val(data.StateID).change();
            setTimeout(setCity, 1000);
            function setCity() {//insere a cidade após 3 segundos
                $('#City').val(data.CityID).change();
                $('#CityID').val($('#City').val());
            }

            if (data.AddressName != "") {
                document.getElementById("Address").readOnly = true;
                $('#Address').val(data.AddressName);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Address").readOnly = false;
                $('#Address').val("");
            }

            if (data.Neighborhood != "") {
                document.getElementById("Neighborhood").readOnly = true;
                $('#Neighborhood').val(data.Neighborhood);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Neighborhood").readOnly = false;
                $('#Neighborhood').val("");
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Error' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

Porém nos dropdown (Cidade e Estado) ainda fica permitindo a alteração. Para o tipo select ele não funciona, existe outra opção?

Comment: Talvez deixar como `readonly` ao invés de `disabled`

Comment: Para o select, você pode usar o seguinte código para desativa-lo:  `$('#selectID').prop('disabled',true);` apenas troque o `selectID` pelo ID do select que deve ser desativado.

Answer (score 3):

Por padrão, o `disabled` não é enviado para o formulário. Creio que a solução seja fazer um `readonly` mesmo, como citado acima.

Comment: no textbox, ao invés de ficar `<input type='text' disabled>` coloque `<input type='text' readonly>`

Comment: @Gabrielfaieri edite sua resposta com o código citado no comentário. Tem um botão embaixo chamado "editar"

Comment: Porque tem que editar a resposta?? eu hein

Comment: Funcionou Gabrielfalieri e @LucasCosta porém nos dropdowns fica permitindo a alteração do usuário. vou editar minha pergunta

Comment: @Gabrielfalieri Porque é assim que preferimos aqui. Os comentários devem ser usados pra coisas triviais, pedir informações, essas coisas e, geralmente, eles são apagados depois de um tempo. Aqui focamos nas perguntas e nas respostas.

Comment: A agora, saquei, que tem os foruns antigos, só tem a pergunta e o code em baixo

Answer (score 0):

Para desativar o select, você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
$('#selectID').prop('disabled',true);
```

Para voltar a ativa-lo, basta remover a propriedade `disabled`:

```
$('#selectID').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Apenas troque o `selectID` pelo ID do select que deve ser desativado.

Answer (score 0):

Um input com a propriedade "disabled" não é enviado junto com os outros campos quando o form é enviado. Se seu objetivo é impedir que o usuário interaja com o campo é melhor utilizar a propriedade readonly.

Se estiver utilizando HTML você faz assim:

```
<input type="text" readonly>
```

Se estiver utilizando XHTML você faz assim:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

Caso seu problema seja setar essa propriedade com javascript você pode utilizar jQuery:

```
$("#State").prop("readonly", true); // Para permitir defina como false
```

Por se tratar de uma propriedade a forma de se obter deveria ser através do objeto HTML + o nome da propriedade, mas no caso do Select os navegadores ainda apresentam problemas com isso. 
Se preferir seguir com javascript puro faça assim para setar seu select:

```
document.getElementById("State").setAttribute("readonly", true);
```

E assim para remover:

```
document.getElementById("State").removeAttribute("readonly");
```

Caso não se trate de um select utilize o método apropriado:

```
document.getElementById("City").readOnly = true;
```

Um dia todos os navegadores irão resolver esse problema e talvez você tenha que voltar nessa implementação para resolver o mesmo problema. Por isso recomendo que você utilize o exemplo com jQuery que já tem um polyfill para isso. Do contrário você mesmo teria que implementar um polyfill neste momento.